# Cucable Plugin not running Scenarios in parallel

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-serenity

I'm trying to run Scenario's in parallel using `Trivago's Cucable Plugin`. To test it before implementing it my project I download this project.

https://github.com/trivago/cucable-plugin/tree/master/example-project

I tried, `mvn clean verify` and it created `*IT.java` files in target folder, but I noticed these are not running in parallel.

How do I know? I added sleep in each statement. Largest sleep is 15 seconds, so the total build should be approx 16 seconds, but it is showing 30 (sum of all sleeps of all scenarios 2+5+15+8) seconds.

**cucable.template**

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "steps",
        features = {"target/parallel/features/[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/[CUCABLE:RUNNER].json"}
)
public class [CUCABLE:RUNNER] {
    // [CUCABLE:CUSTOM:comment]
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucable-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <maven.build.helper.plugin.version>3.0.0</maven.build.helper.plugin.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.2.6</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>

        <generated.runner.directory>${project.build.directory}/parallel/runners</generated.runner.directory>
        <generated.feature.directory>${project.build.directory}/parallel/features</generated.feature.directory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucable-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>parallel</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRunnerTemplateFile>src/test/java/some/template/CucableJavaTemplate.java
                    </sourceRunnerTemplateFile>
                    <sourceFeatures>src/test/resources/features</sourceFeatures>

                    <generatedFeatureDirectory>${generated.feature.directory}</generatedFeatureDirectory>
                    <generatedRunnerDirectory>${generated.runner.directory}</generatedRunnerDirectory>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.build.helper.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${generated.runner.directory}</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Run parallel tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using cucable plugin when Cucumber 4 onwards supports parallel execution without any such plugin. Uses only sure fire plugin and configuration setup is really easy in v4

Comment: Because it doesn't run Scenarios/Features in parallel. I have tried many times but it didn't. Then I moved back to `cucumber jvm parallel plugin from temyers`. Now changing from temyers to trivago's cucable plugin is to get the flexibility to run Scenarios in parallel.

Comment: okay but i would like to update you people have been running test cases in parallel using cucumber v4. Even i myself for last few months. So it works its just you missing something in between.

Comment: You can scenarios in parallel, using cucumber v 4? If Yes, put that as an answer, that'll solve my problem.

Comment: Via JUnit or TestNG ?

Comment: I use JUnit, but if you put a solution for both, it will help other readers also.

Answer (score 1):

### Key Point :

- We shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome.
- We would need to use Cucumber-JVM v4.x.x specially to implement parallel execution without using cucumber-jvm-parallel or cucable plugin
- We would be considering v4.2.6 for the implementation

### Cucumber Parallel Execution via JUnit

**First -** Update POM.xml with correct set of io.cucumber dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Point To Note Down -** There could be an issue like everything is ok but still tests do not execute in parallel and could be if your pom.xml is having direct/transitive dependency of testng. As testNG causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. If you had testng dependency so remove the TestNG dependency or you can take a call to 2 define 2 execution - For TestNG & JUnit and disable one as per your need.

**Second -** Customize Runner class as per your framework need

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

**Third -** Implementing maven surefire plugin which would actually run tests in parallel

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Fourth -** Implement Hooks.java

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.After;

public class Hooks {

    @Before
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        //BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser); your browser setup method
    }
    @After
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
    // more code goes here  
    }
   }
```

### Cucumber Parallel Execution via TestNG

**Note :** In below implementation, we would be reading browser parameter from TestNG.xml file

**First -** Update POM.xml with correct set of io.cucumber dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second -** Customize TestNGRunner class as per your framework need

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional.BaseSteps;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest extends Hooks {

}
```

**Third -** Implement Hooks.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class Hooks extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        //BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser); your browser setup method
    }
}
```

**Fourth -** Update TestNG.xml under /src/test/resources/ as per your TestNGRunner Class and framework need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Testng Cucumber Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="SmokeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.cvs.runner.TestSuiteRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Fifth -** You shall be all set to run automation suite using TestNG in any of the following ways

```
 -    Run TestNG.xml directly from IDE 
 -    From CMD - mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testng.xml
 -    From POM.xml - Using Surefire Plugin

<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>selenium-tests</id>
      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
               <configuration>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>     
         </plugins>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```